# How to call a contact from a retrieved list of contacts in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

This code allows me to retrieve a list of contacts from the user's phone and display them. I am working on some modifications, I added a button "Call" with each individual contact but I am having trouble to understand how to retrieve only the phone number. Once I get the phone number I will just do this to call the number:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("0377778888"));
```

How exatly do I know which number to call? How do I know x user has y number and then pass that number to the intent?

Here is the code: 
Contacts.java

```
package edu.utep.cs.cs4330.easytech;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Contacts extends Activity {
    private ListView mListView;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private Handler updateBarHandler;
    ArrayList<String> contactList;
    Cursor cursor;
    int counter;
    Button callContact;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contacts_list_view);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Reading contacts...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        updateBarHandler = new Handler();

        callContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.callContact);

        // Since reading contacts takes more time, let's run it on a separate thread.
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getContacts();
            }
        }).start();

        // Set onclicklistener to the list item.
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                //TODO Do whatever you want with the list data

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item clicked : \n" + contactList.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    public void getContacts() {
        contactList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String phoneNumber = null;
        String email = null;
        Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
        String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
        String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;
        Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        String Phone_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;
        String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;
        Uri EmailCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
        String EmailCONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID;
        String DATA = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA;
        StringBuffer output;
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        // Iterate every contact in the phone
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            counter = 0;
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                output = new StringBuffer();
                // Update the progress message
                updateBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        pDialog.setMessage("Reading contacts : " + counter++ + "/" + cursor.getCount());
                    }
                });
                String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID));
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DISPLAY_NAME));
                int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
                if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
                    output.append("\nName: " + name);
                    //This is to read multiple phone numbers associated with the same contact
                    Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(PhoneCONTENT_URI, null, Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{contact_id}, null);
                    while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
                        output.append("\n" + phoneNumber);
                    }
                    phoneCursor.close();
                    // Read every email id associated with the contact
                    Cursor emailCursor = contentResolver.query(EmailCONTENT_URI, null, EmailCONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{contact_id}, null);
                    while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        email = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(DATA));
                        output.append("\n Email:" + email);
                    }
                    emailCursor.close();
                }
                // Add the contact to the ArrayList
                contactList.add(output.toString());
            }
            // ListView has to be updated using a ui thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.text1, contactList);
                    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
            // Dismiss the progressbar after 500 millisecondds
            updateBarHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    pDialog.cancel();
                }
            }, 500);
        }
    }
}
```

contacts_list_view.xml
To display a list of contacts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="edu.utep.cs.cs4330.easytech.Home">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/back4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

list_item.xml
Each individual contact

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/callContact"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Call" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/callContact"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/callContact"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any hint is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is Right Way

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + bundle.getString("mobilePhone")));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

dont forget to add permission

Comment: But my question here was more like, how do I know which contact to call? There is a list view that displays all contacts and when you touch the call button it should grab that contacts number and make a call. I know the intent part of it, I just don't know how to get that specific number.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the way to 'check' if the user chose the contact he wanted:
I added a dialog so when you click on the contact in the list the it will ask if you are sure about it:

Note, the SelectUser TmpUser is the a class thats used to arrange the contacts in a list, therfore if you have a list of contacts you shall use the object that has the name,phone number etc that you used to build the list.

```
// A dilaog that will open when a contact is clicked, verify that you want to delete the contact.
protected void areYouSureDialog(final SelectUser tmpUser) {

    final String userPhoneNumber = tmpUser.getPhone();


    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Call a Contact")
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to call:" + userPhoneNumber)
            .setPositiveButton("Call", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    callUser(userPhoneNumber);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Do nothing.
                }
            })
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .show();
}
```

Now we have our Call Contact Function:

```
public void callUser(String phoneNum) {

    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNum + ""));

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(CallActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

And dont forget to add in manifest the permissin:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Hope this answers your question.